# Gymnast what am I?

Tags: riddle

You'd be nothing special without me; I can be in a band.

My neighbours are all taller than me but they're common.

I'm good with children, I know how to calm them down.

I'm sort of like a gymnast...

**What am I?**

Hint 1:

> Hold on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> Thumb?

You'd be nothing special without me; I can be in a band.

> is band the group of fingers in hand? or sometimes not when gesturing OK sign **OP Edit:** *A thumb can wear a ring and be 'in a band', we wouldn't be anything without thumbs, because we couldn't grab things, use tools etc.*

My neighbours are all taller than me but they're common.

> Other fingers are taller in your hand but common in a hand **OP Edit:** *Thumbs are uncommon among other animals.*

I'm good with children, I know how to calm them down.

> thumb suck in babies or OK sign for praising kids

I'm sort of like a gymnast...

> Well thumb is the most flexible among other fingers

Hint 1:

Hold on!

> not sure if this means stop gesture of your hand **OP Edit:** *You need your thumb to hold onto things.*

Comment: You don't necessarily need your thumbs to hold things, if you can hold them with your other fingers. Examples are pencils, ropes, handles, and other objects that are thin.

Answer (score 9):

This feels like a shot in the dark, but here goes:

Is it...

> **RUBBER**

You'd be nothing special without me; I can be in a band.

> A reference to rubber bands.

My neighbours are all taller than me but they're common.

> In plantations, rubber trees are not nearly as tall as their wild counterparts.

I'm good with children, I know how to calm them down.

> Pacifiers are often made of rubber.

I'm sort of like a gymnast...

> Rubber is a very elastic (flexible) material, like a good gymnast.

Comment: Nice answer but not what I'm looking for

Comment: I figured that was a long shot. But, like the other 'what am I' puzzle you posted, I was able to draw quite a few connections to an answer you weren't looking for. Not sure if this is problematic or not.

Answer (score 3):

Could you possibly be

> Carbon?

*You'd be nothing special without me*

> Humans are carbon-based life forms. Without carbon, we would not have organic compounds, and life on Earth would not exist.

*I can be in a band*

> This refers to a diamond ring, like an engagement band. Diamonds are a form of carbon.

*My neighbours are all taller than me but they're common*

> In nature, carbon often bond with oxygen and nitrogen. They are "neighbors" when they are chemically bonded, and they are also "neighbors" in the periodic table. These elements have higher atomic numbers and atomic mass than carbon, and are the [most common elements](http://teachertech.rice.edu/Participants/louviere/comp.html) in the atmosphere.

*I'm good with children, I know how to calm them down*

> When a child has an upset stomach, they may take [calcium carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate#Health_and_dietary_applications) as an antacid.

*I'm sort of like a gymnast*

> This could have multiple meanings. One may be a reference to carbon fiber materials that are strong and can bend easily (like a gymnast). Another meaning is that carbon comes in many forms, and is therefore "flexible" in a sense.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> **Rock**

You'd be nothing special without me; I can be in a band.

> Sometimes bands play rock music.

My neighbours are all taller than me but they're common.

> Not totally sure. In Rock, Paper, Scissors, the paper and scissor gestures are longer. Plus, both scissors and paper are more common in everyday life.

I'm good with children, I know how to calm them down.

> Rocking chair, rocker, Rock-a-Bye Baby

I'm sort of like a gymnast...

> Compact and strong